# React Native : Attempted to assign to readonly property

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, javascript-objects

I am trying to check if the entry exists in the AsycStore and if it doesn't exist then, I create an object and set it.
And there is a return statement that returns the dataobject.

Here is the pseudocode-

```
AsyncStorage.getItem("dataobject").then((do) => {
  if(do == undefined)
  {
    console.log("initializing obj + setting data");
    var dobj = "data object";
    dobj.isdirty = true;
    AsyncStorage.setItem("dataobject",dobj);
  }
  return AsyncStorage.getItem("dataobject");
}).done();
},
```

I am getting an error in console -

```
W/ReactNativeJS: 'Error: Attempted to assign to readonly property.\n stack: \n  <unknown>

index.android.bun…:53047\n  tryCallOne                           
index.android.bun…:5094\n  <unknown>                            
index.android.bun…:5160\n  <unknown>                            
index.android.bun…:3399\n  callTimer                            
index.android.bun…:2954\n  callImmediates                       
index.android.bun…:3003\n  <unknown>                            
index.android.bun…:2523\n  guard                                
index.android.bun…:2452\n  __callImmediates                     
index.android.bun…:2523\n  <unknown>                            
index.android.bun…:2503\n  guard                                
index.android.bun…:2452\n  invokeCallbackAndReturnFlushedQueue  index.android.bun…:2501\n URL: http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true\n line: 53047\n message: Attempted to assign to readonly property.'
```

I am not really sure what is the readonly property I am trying to assign. The line number that is being warned is this line - "dobj.isdirty = true";

Should I not add a property to an object? How do I solve this problem? What's the right way of doing it?

Screenshot-

[image: Attempted to assign to readonly property width=100]

Comment: I also faced this issue. In my case: I created a custom "Text" component. But import "Text" from 'react-native' and pass some props which are accepted by my custom "Text" component. But build-in Text component doesn't have these kind of props.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can probably accomplish this by using the .catch, which should throw if there is not a value there. Something like:

```
AsyncStorage.getItem("dataobject")
.then((do) => {
  this.setState({
    myData: do.toJSON();
  })
})
.catch(() => {
   console.log("initializing obj + setting data");
   var dobj = {};
   dobj.isdirty = true;
   AsyncStorage.setItem("dataobject",JSON.stringify(dobj));
});
```

Comment: Yes. A code something of the same kind helped me fix the issue :) Thanks Nader. A catch block is something I can add as well.

Comment: So did you find what was the underlying issue? I'm having the same problem / getting a similar error message and unable to reproduce or understand what's causing it.

Comment: If any ones getting this error, try to make a copy of the object and update it. obj = { ...obj, newData }

Answer (score -3):

Is dobj a string or an object?

`var dobj = "data object";
dobj.isdirty = true;`

In the second line, dobj.isdirty is undefined and you're trying to set that ("undefined" is a readonly property of JS).

Now if you're trying to do

`var dobj = {};
dobj.isdirty = true;`

Then instead you should do

`var dobj = {};
dobj['isdirty'] = true;`

OR

`var dobj = {isdirty: true};`

Comment: Even if dobj.isdirty is undefined, doing dobj.isdirty = true; actually defines it.